# How to draw a smooth curve?

Tags: c++, qt, smoothing, spline, qchart

I have a set of points to plot and their coordinates are stored in

```
QVector<double> x(200), y(200);
```

I'd like to connect them with some smooth curve, any, say, splines. Or a bigger array of points between knots would also suffice. My try is

```
customPlot->addGraph();
customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
customPlot->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));
customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("Index");
customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("Amplitude");
customPlot->xAxis->setRange(0, 200);
customPlot->yAxis->setRange(-3, 3);
```

I tried using:

- `QPainterPath` class, but it didn't work.
- `QEasingCurve` class, its functions might help, but there are no examples and I don't know how to use them.

Comment: A `QEasingCurve` is meant to be used in animations. It's not designed for use in drawing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code I would say you are using [Qt Charts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-index.html).

There is a [QSplineSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplineseries.html) you can use that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to draw QSplineSeries on a QGraphicScene without using QtCharts?

Comment: No, that is not possible. If you want to do it by yourself you can check the code in splinechartitem.cpp of the QtCharts module. It is far from trivial though.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that already. I'm currently looking into some other alternatives, using bezier curves. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764011/how-to-draw-a-smooth-curved-line-that-goes-through-several-points-in-qt/40764363?noredirect=1#comment68756932_40764363