# How to smooth a chart?

Tags: c++, qt, smoothing, qchart, qchartview

How can I add smoothing to a chart in Qt?

[image: chart]

```cpp
QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
   
foreach (int key, chart_data[0].get_spectra_data().keys() )
{
    *series << QPoint( key, chart_data[0].get_spectra_data().value( key ) );
}
```

```cpp
QChart *chart;
chart = new QChart();
chart->legend()->hide();
chart->addSeries(series);
chart->createDefaultAxes();
chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");
chartView->setChart( chart );

chartView = new QChartView();
chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing smooth curve with Qt C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358836/drawing-smooth-curve-with-qt-c)

Answer (score 0):

Need to change

```
*series << QPoint( key, chart_data[0].get_spectra_data().value( key ) );
```

into

```
series->append( key, chart_data[0].get_spectra_data().value( key ) );
```